# How to check for variable existence in codeigniter(php)? newb question

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

Hey I'm new to php and codeigniter.  I know that in codeigniter's view you can echo a variable like

```
<?php echo $var ?>
```

but if say, I don't pass the variable $var, I get a nasty

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
```

in my html source code.  I've worked with django before an in their template, if the variable doesn't exist, they simply don't render it.  Is there a way in php/codeigniter to say 'if $var exists do smthing else do nothing' ?

I tried:

```
<?php if($title): ?>
    <?php echo $title ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but that was an error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `isset()` function to test if a variable has been declared.

```
if (isset($var)) echo $var;
```

Use the `empty()` function to test if a variable has no content such as `NULL, "", false or 0`.

Comment: ah i see very nice and simple... btw when dealing with codeigniter's view <?php ?> tags, can u put any php code in there that u normally can in any php file?

Comment: `<?php if (isset($var)) echo $var; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I create a new helper function (See: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/helpers.html) called 'exists' that checks if the variable isset and not empty:

```
function exists($string) {
  if (isset($string) && $string) {
    return $string;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Include that in the controller:

```
$this->load->helper('exists');
```

Then in the view I just have:

```
<?php echo exists($var) ?>
```

If you wanted you could put the echo straight in the function, but not sure if that's bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator

```
echo isset($var) ? $var : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar noob question of:

> How to check if a variable is set to null, undefined or 0. But allow the 0 option?

I landed here and refactored some of the answers into this:

```
if (empty($a) && $a != 0)
```

Which passed testing for my case.